# Generic annotation of arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I find this snippet of code in twitter, it is hard to me to understand what happens here, all I can see that the OP of this code is creating an annotation, I can see also that the OP use array of arrays in this code, and also use generics  :

```
class Woww {
    @Wow Wow @Wow [] @Wow [] wow(@Wow Wow[] wow@Wow[])@Wow[]@Wow[] {
        return new Wow@Wow[]@Wow[]@Wow[]@Wow[]{
            {wow}
        };
    }
}

@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@interface Wow {
}
```

Can you please explain to me what happens exactly in this code, and how we can use it in a simple example,
Thanks

Comment: Mind blown... that's valid code, incredible

Answer (score 3):

There are two tricks at play here:

#### Type Use Annotation Instances

First, since Java 8 the [*use*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE_USE) of a type can be annotated with an annotation, and this *includes* individual array dimensions. From the [Java Language Specification, 10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1):

> Each bracket pair in an array type may be annotated by type annotations (§9.7.4). An annotation applies to the bracket pair (or ellipsis, in a variable arity parameter declaration) that follows it.

#### Placement of Array Dimensions

Second, according to the [Java Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) array dimensions for the return type can be placed both with the return type and after the list of parameters, and similarly for individual variables.

#### Example

This means that code like this (the method's parameter declaration):

```
@Wow Wow[] wow@Wow[]
```

is the same as:

```
@Wow Wow[]@Wow[] wow
```

once the square brackets are grouped with the element type, where the array type and inner dimensions are annotated with `@Wow`.